# match values from array with values of another array and return corresponding values in new array as loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having trouble finding a solution to the following problem.

I need to take the first value of one array (`$split`), find it in another array (`$array`) and return a corresponding value into a new array (`$matched`), then loop until all values in `$split` have been matched and returned (in order) to `$matched`.

I've annotated my code below to explain further.

```
<?php

$split = explode('/', '1/2/3');

// $split can be any length and any order

// EG. $split = explode('/', '1/2/3/66/4/9'); 

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages");

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row;
}

foreach($new_array as $array) {       

    // take first value from $split
    // match value with 'id' of $array
    // return corresponding 'filename'
    // set as first value of $matched

    $matched = // 

    // loop until all values from $split have been matched
    // and the corresponding filename has been added to $matched.

}

$join = implode('/', $matched); // join $matched as string.

?>
```

Comment: Not sure with the info provided, but would it not make more sense to modify the SQL query to only return the correct rows? "SELECT id, filename FROM pages WHERE id IN (1,2,3,66,4,9)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let'see:

- You have list of numbers (ids),
- you have map: id -> filename,
- you need filenames ( imploded by slash )

so:

```
<?php

// $split can be any length and any order
// EG. $split = explode('/', '1/2/3/66/4/9'); 
$split = explode('/', '1/2/3');

// NB!
$split = array_flip( $split );

$result = $connection->query("SELECT id, filename FROM pages");

/* I need exactly map id -> filename for implode() */
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $new_array[$row['id']] = $row['filename'];
}

$matched = array_intersect_key($new_array, $split);

$join = implode('/', $matched); // join $matched as string.

?>
```

Comment: perfect, and very clean. Thank you very much.

Comment: solution from @Matt.C (retrieving only matched rows) is better

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example:

```
    // ... some code
    $matched = array();
    foreach ( $split AS $key ) {
        if ( isset($array[$key]) ) {
            $matched[] = $array[$key];
        }
    }
    return $matched;
    // ... more code
```

Comment: Would this replace my current `foreach` loop? As `$array` is only defined in the current `foreach` loop as `foreach($new_array as $array)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would build a mysql query this way:

```
SELECT id, filename FROM pages WHERE id IN(1,2,3,66,4,9) ORDER BY FIELD(id,1,2,3,66,4,9)
```

And then, in php:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   $match[] = $row;
}
```

Comment: This seems very clean but how would I output the results? as desired, as a string delimited by a '/'?

Comment: The string exploded in $split is also dynamically populated so this wouldn't work if the string only had one part ie. '1' instead of '1/2/3/4'